# Build completed with a result of 'Failed' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am unable to build my app on unity, it is always shoeing gradle build error

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 26 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
(UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in
C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
[0x0007f] in
C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Gradle build always shows error in most versions of Unity android. Change it to "internal" in build settings and try again.

Comment: Does not appear... I believe is not longer supported on newer versions...

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was that I added a preprocessor directive in front of every `using UnityEditor;`

For example:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR 
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```

Also, I need to change the C# API compatibility Level, because I was using some functions from a newer API. You can change it under **Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings -> Api Compatibility Level** (from .NET Standard 2.0 to **.NET 4.x**)